# my table doesn't overflow div at all

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Before I start with my question I want you to know that I've search over and over this. I found many different answers  on how to make my table to overflow the div with no result. The problem is that my table won't overflow at all even though it shows the scrollbar in some case (some other codes that I've used). It goes always 100% width to the div. If I increase width in a column it will just resize the rest of the columns. So I would like you to tell me what I am doing wrong and if you have any suggestions. Thank you all in advance.

You can see the complete table here: http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/XJqwYy

```
<div class="scrollit">

<table class="qwe3" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" class="qwe1">title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="qwe2">
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS (scroll is at the bottom)

```
.qwe1 { background:#202B39; border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; height:40px; font-size:20px; color:#FFF; font-weight: 300; text-align:center; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); vertical-align:middle; }

.qwe2 { 
 color:#202B39;
 background:#56c9d6; 
 font-size:13px; font-weight: 400; 
 text-align:center; 
 vertical-align:middle; 
}

qwe3 {table-layout:fixed;
overflow:"hidden";
}

.scrollit {overflow:auto;}
```

Comment: Sounds like you prefer not to set a fixed width on the `<table>` is that true?

Comment: hmmm.. that worked in my first attempts  but I am afraid that it will not look good on small devices .. That's why I was trying to avoid fixed values. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `min-width` and `max-width` to the `<td>` seems be able to fix it.

I created a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/1yjbnfxn/2/

HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Table have position absolute.. and add a wrapper that has position relative along with overflow auto... It should do the trick